# MongoDB indexed find performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple question.

If we do a `db.collection.find({_id:ObjectId("an id")})` on a 1 million rows, does it take the same time as 1 billion rows?

if possible to explain why it does or does not take the same time, knowing that _id is an indexed field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB uses [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for indexes which have a time complexity of O(log n) for search.

```
log 1M = 6
log 1B = 9
```

So a search over 1 billion docs will take roughly 50% longer than a search over 1 million docs.